# Wildfly/JBoss and LDAP datasource

Tags: jboss, ldap, datasource, wildfly

Is it possible to define (in AS context but not in deploy context) an LDAP datasource in Wildfly/JBoss to access at LDAP like a database performing simple searches? How to do that with connection pool like a SQL database query?

Thanks a lot.